# Export chart as image - with click of a button

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to create a button that would export a chart in sheet "Graphs" as a jpeg file. This is the code I have, however it keeps on showing this error:

> runtime error 424: object required

Specifically for this:

```
Set myChart = Graphs.ChartObjects(3).Name = "Chart4"
```

And here's the code

```
Sub ExportChart()
    Dim myChart As Chart
    Dim myFileName As String
    Set myChart = Graphs.ChartObjects(3).Name = "Chart4"
    myFileName = "myChart.jpg"
    On Error Resume Next
    Kill ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & myFileName
    myChart.Export Filename:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & myFileName, Filtername:="PNG"
    MsgBox "OK"
    Set myChart = Nothing
End Sub
```

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Is this what you are trying?

Also if you are trying to save it as jpg then why a png filter? I have changed "myChart.jpg" to "myChart.png". Change as applicable.

```
Sub ExportChart()
    Dim objChrt As ChartObject
    Dim myChart As Chart

    Set objChrt = Sheets("Graphs").ChartObjects(3)
    Set myChart = objChrt.Chart

    myFileName = "myChart.png"

    On Error Resume Next
    Kill ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & myFileName
    On Error GoTo 0

    myChart.Export Filename:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & myFileName, Filtername:="PNG"

    MsgBox "OK"
End Sub
```

Comment: You are just too fast!  One note to the OP, that's incorporated in Siddharth's answer is to add On Error GoTo 0 as soon as possible in your code, or you will mask errors.  In this case you needed the ChartObject's Chart Object :) which is always confusing.

Comment: I am trying to make up for the last few days of inactivity :D

Answer (score 9):

Thanks, I needed this to extract all charts in an image and it's almost midnight.
Minor changes to the code above did the trick.

```
Sub ExportChart()
    Dim WS As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim SaveToDirectory As String

    Dim objChrt As ChartObject
    Dim myChart As Chart

    SaveToDirectory = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\"

    For Each WS In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        WS.Activate 'go there
        For Each objChrt In WS.ChartObjects
            objChrt.Activate
            Set myChart = objChrt.Chart

            myFileName = SaveToDirectory & WS.Name & "_" & objChrt.Index & ".png"

            On Error Resume Next
            Kill SaveToDirectory & WS.Name & Index & ".png"
            On Error GoTo 0

            myChart.Export Filename:=myFileName, Filtername:="PNG"
        Next
    Next

    MsgBox "OK"
End Sub
```

Comment: I ran your code but nothing was exported. Any idea why? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Working off the examples given by @Miles and @Siddarth Rout, I just created this variation. As a note, this is for the backend of an app that tracks user feedback, which needs to be presented broken out in different ways for a variety of audiences. While we wait for the developers to build the reporting end of the app, I'm downloading the data from SQL as a .csv, massaging the crap out of it in Excel, which then feeds ***27*** individual charts and graphs (*soon to be 28 if we can get the final user group online!*)

I went through and named each of the charts what I need the resultant files to be called so I can upload the graphics to the app server, overwriting the previous week's graphs, automagically (for the end users) updating the reporting.

[image: Renaming a graph object in Excel]

Since the file names need to remain exactly the same, naming the graphs made the most sense, so I never need to touch that part again. (*Until doing this today, I've been copying each chart, pasting into Paint, then saving as a PNG, and saving over the previous week's files so I could just click on the old one, which automatically assigns that name to the Save As process. Finding the code above and a way to make it even slicker will both save me about 30 minutes a week AND remove 27 possible manual errors... pretty good investment! If only I had made it... a year ago?*)

```
' Ctrl-Shift-A to run

Sub ExportChart()
Dim WS As Excel.Worksheet
Dim SaveToDirectory As String

Dim objChrt As ChartObject
Dim myChart As Chart

SaveToDirectory = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\"

For Each WS In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    WS.Activate 'go there
    For Each objChrt In WS.ChartObjects
        objChrt.Activate
        Set myChart = objChrt.Chart

        ' Change from above: using ChartObject.Name to individually name each exported PNG file
        myFileName = SaveToDirectory & objChrt.Name & ".png" 
        
        On Error Resume Next
        Kill SaveToDirectory & WS.Name & Index & ".png"
        On Error GoTo 0

        myChart.Export Filename:=myFileName, Filtername:="PNG"
    Next
Next

MsgBox "Eeeaaagle!!"
End Sub
```