# Save the current graph in a userform chart by using a 'save as' function linked to a command button?

Tags: excel, vba, save-as, excel-charts

I have a userform that allows me to calculate values and draw graphs from these values. The graphs are stored in an Excel sheet during this step.
The userform contains a chart that allows me to display inside the graphs I have drawn.
A spin button allows me to navigate between the graphs in the chart. For example if the spin button value is equal to 1 and I have drawn 3 graphs in my Excel sheet, the first graph that has been drawn will be displayed in the userform chart.
Now what I'm trying to do is to create a macro linked to a command button that allows me to save the graph that is displayed in the chart (the current graph).
I want to use a 'save as' interface because the user has to choose where to save the graph.

I found the following code on a forum:

```
Sub filesave()  
    Dim bFileSaveAs As Boolean  
    bFileSaveAs = Application.Dialogs(xlDialogSaveAs).Show  
End Sub
```

By clicking my command button associated to this function, a "save as" window opens but allows me to save the only the Excel workbook.
So, I would like to adapt this code to my problem. If you have any ideas, I'm all ears.

Comment: What do you want to save the graph as? A picture?

Comment: Yes, as a JPG for example.

Comment: Perhaps helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11939087/export-chart-as-image-with-click-of-a-button

Comment: Thank you very much. But in this example I think that the graph is exported where the workbook is located. I want something different. Indeed, I want to open a 'save as' windows linked to my graph I want to export.

Comment: Look at `Application.GetSaveAsFilename` - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.getsaveasfilename