# Script exports only white images

Tags: excel, vba, image

I am trying to automatically export pictures of every sheet of my workbook.

When I check the Export Folder I see, that there are only correct formatted images (Height and Width) as blank white without any content.

```vb
Sub ExportWorkbookAsImage()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim strSheetName As String
Dim sView As String
For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    sView = ActiveWindow.View
    strSheetName = ws.Name
    zoom_coef = 100 / ws.Parent.Windows(1).Zoom
    Set area = ws.Range(ws.Cells(1, 1), ws.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell))
    area.CopyPicture xlPrinter
    Set chartobj = ws.ChartObjects.Add(1, 1, area.Width * zoom_coef, area.Height * zoom_coef)
    With chartobj
        .Chart.Paste
        .Activate
        .Chart.Export "C:\Users\PC\Desktop\Neuer Ordner" & "\" & strSheetName & ".jpg"
        .Delete
    End With

Next ws
End Sub
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Export chart as image - with click of a button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11939087/export-chart-as-image-with-click-of-a-button)

Answer (score 0):

I made some changes to your code, basically selecting the desired range and pasting it as a picture. Then copying/pasting this picture inside the temporary chart object.

```
Sub ExportWorkbookAsImage()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim strSheetName As String
    Dim sView As String
    Dim activeShape As Shape

    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        ws.Activate
            
        Range(ws.Cells(1, 1), ws.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell)).Select
        Selection.Copy
        ActiveSheet.Pictures.Paste(link:=False).Select
        Set activeShape = ActiveSheet.Shapes(ActiveWindow.Selection.Name)
        
        Set chartObj = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Add(Left:=ActiveCell.Left, _
                                                    Width:=activeShape.Width, _
                                                    Top:=ActiveCell.Top, _
                                                    Height:=activeShape.Height)
        With chartObj
            .ShapeRange.Fill.Visible = msoFalse
            .ShapeRange.Line.Visible = msoFalse
            
            activeShape.Copy
            .Activate
            ActiveChart.Paste
            .Chart.Paste
            .Activate
            .Chart.Export "C:\Users\PC\Desktop\Neuer Ordner\" & ws.Name & ".jpg"
            .Delete
            activeShape.Delete
        End With
    
    Next ws

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. Unfortunately the script fails in the second sheet with a failure.         -> ActiveSheet.Pictures.Paste(link:=False).Select is the Breakpoint. When i press F5 the whole time the script works fine and does what it should.

Comment: Okay, the cript works when i deactivate the clipboard function. That's it. Thank you :)